# Image not Zoom On double tap in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, zooming

In my application having gallery functionality.For Scrolling image i used **REPagedScrollView** and i want to image zoom on pinch using 2 finger and also want zoom on double tap but i unable to to zoom image on double tap 
please resolved my problem.
I tried by below code :

**.h file**

```
    @interface ViewPhotoVC : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
    {
        REPagedScrollView *scrollView;
        UIScrollView *image_scroll;
        int current_page;
        BOOL is_FullScreen;
    }
    @property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *slider_view;
```

.m file

```
-(void)video_image_Gallery
{
    scrollView = [[REPagedScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.slider_view.bounds];
    scrollView.delegate=self;
    // scrollView.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    // scrollView.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    current_page=0;
 for(int i=0;i<[self.PhotoImgArr count];i++){
 self.image_view = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.slider_view.frame.size.width,  self.slider_view.frame.size.height)];
        //        scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, screenwidth, screenheight);

        image_scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenwidth,screenheight)];
        self.image_view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        self.image_view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        self.image_view.clipsToBounds = true;
        self.image_view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.image_view.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);

        self.image_view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image1.png"];

        self.image_view.imageURL =[NSURL URLWithString:[self.PhotoImgArr objectAtIndex:i]];
        self.image_view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:247.0/255.0 green:246.0/255.0 blue:241.0/255.0 alpha:1];


        [image_scroll setDelegate:self];
        [image_scroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
        [image_scroll setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
        [image_scroll setMaximumZoomScale:8.0];
        image_scroll.tag=i+1;
        self.PlayVideoBtn.tag=i+1;
        self.image_view.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

        image_scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.image_view.bounds.size.width-500, self.image_view.bounds.size.height-300);
        image_scroll.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;

      //  [image_scroll setMinimumZoomScale:[image_scroll frame].size.width / [self.image_view frame].size.width];
        [image_scroll setZoomScale:[image_scroll minimumZoomScale]];
        [image_scroll addSubview:self.image_view];
        [image_scroll addSubview:self.PlayVideoBtn];
        [image_scroll addSubview:self.videoImg];
        scrollView.tag=0;
//        self.PlayVideoBtn.tag=0;
        [scrollView addPage:image_scroll];
    }
    [self.slider_view addSubview:scrollView];

    self.index_lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %lu",(int)self.selected_index+1,(unsigned long)[self.PhotoImgArr count]];
    [scrollView scrollToPageWithIndex:self.selected_index animated:YES];
}




- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1
{
    if(scrollView1.tag ==0){
        CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView1.frame.size.width;
        current_page = floor((scrollView1.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2.0) / pageWidth) + 1;
        self.index_lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %lu",current_page+1,(unsigned long)[self.PhotoImgArr count]];
        if(current_page+1==self.PhotoImgArr.count)
        {
            self.nextBtn.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
            self.nextImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"disable_next.png"];
        }
        else if(current_page==0)
        {
            self.prevBtn.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
            self.prevImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"disable_prev.png"];

        }
        else
        {
            self.nextBtn.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            self.prevBtn.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

            self.nextImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"next.png"];
            self.prevImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"prev.png"];


        }

    }
}
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1 {
    if([self.PhotoOrVideo isEqualToString:@"Photo"])
    {
    if([[scrollView1 viewWithTag:scrollView1.tag].subviews count]>0){
        return [[scrollView1 viewWithTag:scrollView1.tag].subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: @SaurabhJain I solved this issue. this is old post.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code:

```
-(void)setScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    _scrollView=scrollView;
    _scrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.2;
    _scrollView.maximumZoomScale=3.0;
    _scrollView.delegate=self;
}
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}
-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    [self.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
}
```